# How to display telugu font in android

Tags: android, character-encoding, typeface, text-rendering

I want to display Telugu font in android In 4.0 and above devices Telugu font will support automatically but I have problem in 4.0 below devices.I have used following code but Telugu is not rendering properly.

```
   Typeface tf= Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/gautami.ttf");
   TextView telugu=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.telugu);
   telugu.setTypeface(tf);
   telugu.setText("హైదరాబాద్");
```

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

remove **`/font`** to solve your problem

You can use a subfolder called fonts but it must go in the **`assets`** folder not the **`res`** folder.

```
assets/res
```

#### Android

```
TextView telugu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.telugu);
Typeface Typefacetf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "gautami.ttf");
telugu.setTypeface(Typefacetf);
telugu.setText("హైదరాబాద్");
```

Comment: why you are using external library if android provide natively.

Comment: but giving Hard coded value on TextView is not good android so just define it in string.xml and your work is done.

Comment: OP's main problem is write `/font` so remove this to solve this problem.

Comment: Typeface tf= Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/gautami.ttf"); clearly says that its in assets/fonts/gautami.ttf.

Comment: Hi same problem text is not rendering properly if I used above code in android below 4.0 devices.

Comment: are you removing `fonts/` ?

Comment: @hcp i think your font format ttf is not valid file. download telungu ttf file from another website. and try again. give me response

Comment: @user1153551 I have tried lot of TTFs but nothing is working perfectly.Please can you suggest any TTF.

Answer (score 0):

Just define your font in string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="text_your_name">హైదరాబాద్</string>
</resources>
```

because in that encoding is utf-8 is there so it will render properly.

now for setting that text you can use this:

```
telugu.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.text_your_name));
```

**EDIT:**

Now see answer over here it may help you out :: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267292/tamil-font-in-android/15496145#15496145) they having same problem like you.

Comment: Hi same problem text is not rendering properly if I used above code in android below 4.0 devices.

Comment: I have tested it in 2.2 emulator. It is not working properly.I will check it in 2.3.3 emulator and let you know.

Comment: no just check it in a real device so you will get exact problem.

Comment: Hi I have tested it in real device still problem exists.Device version 2.3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Write a item inside string.xml inside values folder

```
<string name="your_text">హైదరాబాద్</string>
```

Then keep your font file in assets folder

Then create custom typeface in java code using font from assets folder

```
Typeface custom_type_face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "gautami.ttf");
```

Use this to your TextView

```
TextView telugu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.telugu);
telugu.setTypeface(custom_type_face);
```

Set Text from strings.xml folder

```
telugu.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.your_text));
```