# Tamil Language (தமிழ்) text was not displaying properly in Android mobile app using Firemonkey

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin, tamil

I'm using Delphi 10.1 for developing android mobile application and I have tried to display Tamil language (தமிழ்) texts in TLabel and TComboBox and it was properly in windows application but it was not displaying properly in android mobile app and should need to add any specific font to display this language. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: See [Tamil fonts in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15496145/576719)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tamil fonts in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267292/tamil-fonts-in-android)

Comment: I have tried mylai & Bamini but the text was not displaying properly. Should I need to do any other changes other than assigning Font.FamilyName ? Please help me out in this

Comment: How can I able to access this [library] (https://github.com/mayooresan/Android-TamilUtil) using Delphi 10.1 for android application?